# Any way to fix this TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when opening Python 2 Pickle file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to unpickle a python 2 pickle file in python 3 using the following code:

```
with open("final_project_dataset.pkl", "rb") as data_file:
        data_dict = pickle.load(data_file, encoding='utf8')
```

I get the following errorError:

```
---> data_dict = pickle.load(data_file, encoding='utf8')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I've tried a number of different encodings including bytes and latin1, none of which work.

Comment: What sort of objects are in the pickle file?  If there are any user-defined class instances, are you sure that the classes can be successfully instantiated under Python 3?

Comment: It's a large file of dictionaries of dictionaries. It's the Enron dataset to be more specific.

Comment: What happens when you just use `pickle.load(data_file)` ??

Comment: same error: 

data_dict = pickle.load(data_file)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I just downloaded the pkl file from https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects, and had absolutely no problem reading it using the exact command you used.  Is it possible your file is corrupted somehow?

Comment: I redownloaded it and it's still not working, I'll  keep searching